# Get clip Start Frame Number and end frame number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just tried this so far. I want to get the frame number of start and end in order to calculate total frame number of specific clip for testing purposes.

```
 public Animation anim;
        [![enter image description here][1]][1]
        void Reset () {
            anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
            Debug.Log(anim.GetClipCount());
            foreach (AnimationState a in anim) {
                if (a.time != 100f || a.time != 50f) {
                    Debug.Log(a.name +" has lenght "+ a.length);
                } 
            }
        }
```

Is there any way available I google but didn't find solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think i didn't understand, but what do you mean by frame number of start and end?

By what I understood, you want to know in which frame ( of the 3D model animation ) does each state start / end. There is actually a way to do this, but it makes use of UnityEditor classes ( since you have to access the asset import settings of the model ), so though it would work in the Editor, the standalone version won't.

Actually, if you just need to know which frame does the clips start and end you can check it on the Animation import settings:

[pic related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUVZB.png)

If after all you want to check it via script ( even though it won't work as a standalone ), you should read [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporterClipAnimation.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: by "Editor Mode" you mean "in the Unity Editor" or "while not in Play mode"?

Comment: yeah i want in play mode but u said it is not possible in standalone